# ng-model in angular disable value in textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, textbox

I am trying to develop a page in mvc-asp with angularjs. I have a textbox like this :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="Name">نام خودرو</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="Name" ng-model="Name" required name="Name" type="text" value="@Edit.Name">
</div>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="frm.Name.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="frm.Name.$error.required">نام خودرو را وارد کنید</span>
</span>
```

As you can see I validate the textbox using angularjs. Everything work fine, but the problem is `value="@Edit.Name"` I put this option for editing in edit controller I push my value to a viewbag called `Edit` and I pass the value to the textbox using `value="@Edit.Name"`.

As you can see in the code, when i click on the edit button the value should be passed to the textbox, but the textbox is empty, when i remove `ng-model="Name"`, it works fine and the textbox is filled with the value ..

Why ?

Comment: That is because ng-model is setting the value for you. If you check $scope.Name in controller it will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you specify the `ng-model` directive, angular updates the value of the input to the value of `Name` in your controller, which I can only assume is a null value.

Setting the value directly on the input when you generate the page does not update the underlying model value. What's really happening is that you're generating the page with a value in the input, and angular is immediately updating the value of the input based on the value (`null`) of the `ng-model` (`Name`).

You need to do things the angular way and set the value of `Name` in your controller scope to the value you want populated.

Unfortunately it's too involved to be able to provide you information here about how to structure your .NET MVC app with AngularJS. However, I would suggest that you go through some beginner angular tutorials on the https://angularjs.org/ site and YouTube (this one seems helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKkUN-mJtPQ&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl) to understand how angular works on its own apart from .NET.

Once you understand how angular itself works then you'll be able to incorporate it into a .NET MVC app. I suggest not using .NET MVC as you learn angular since the structure of the 2 applications are fundamentally different and you'll run into a lot of issues as a beginner.

Here is a hint though when you do use them together: use angular `resources` (handles ajax) and `services/factories/providers` to call your controller methods and retrieve data for angular to bind to. The MVC views themselves will not handle databinding at all.

Comment: I am so new in angular js here is my scope     <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('validateCtrl', function ($scope) {
        
        });
    </script>

Comment: Could you please give me a details of the solution ?